# Given a sum of orthogonal polynomials $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{d}a_k P_k(x)=0$ where $x>0$, can I say that $a_k=0 \ \forall k$?

Tags: summation, orthogonal-polynomials

I think I can use the recursive argument that because the leading coefficient of the highest order polynomial $P_k$ is unequal to zero the corresponding $a_{d}=0$.

Comment: This is true even when multiple of your polynomials have the same degree. If the sum is zero on any open interval, it is zero everywhere, and orthogonal vectors are always linearly independent

Comment: On the other hand, you can also drop the orthogonality assumption and replace it by the assumption that your polynomials have different degrees. Both imply linear independence